# Form to mail action not working after clicking submit

Tags: php, html

I have a html form on my index page and after the fields are been filled and submit button is clicked, the form action moves to a new page I named "indexform.php" but does not execute the php code on the "indexform.php" page.

Below is my html form code:

```
<form method="post" action="indexform.php">

<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">

<input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">

<input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">

<input name="budget" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Budget">

<textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="What kind of content marketing services are you looking for?"></textarea>

<input type="submit" formaction="indexform.php" name="submit" value="Send Message">

</form>
```

Below is my php code on indexform.php page:

```
<?php

$mail_to_send_to = "joseph@digitage.net";
$from_email = "joseph@digitage.net";
$sendflag = $_REQUEST['sendflag'];
if ($sendflag == "send") {
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $budget = $_REQUEST['budget'];
    $headers = "From: $from_email" . "\r\n" . "Subject: $subject" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
    $a = mail($mail_to_send_to, "Message from a Home page contact form", $message, $headers);
    if ($a) {
        print("Message was sent, you can send another one");
    } else {
        print("Message wasn't sent, please check that you have changed emails in 
the bottom");
    }
}
?>
```

I don't get any message after the form action is been performed.

Comment: change your code to  <input type="submit"  name="sendflag" value="Send Message">

Comment: Since your http method is post, you should be using $_POST["sendflag"] ??

Comment: change the just submit button "<input type="submit"  name="sendflag" value="send">"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `formaction="index.php"` attribute in your button element. As long as you have the `action="indexform.php"` in your `<form>` tag, it will send the POST request to that URL.

```
<form method="post" action="indexform.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" />
    <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" />
    <input name="budget" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Budget" />
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="What kind of content marketing services are you looking for?"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

I noticed in your PHP, you're checking for the input field `'sendflag'`, but this has no input directive in your HTML, so really every time you check for 'sendflag', it will always be NULL. Also, you should really be using `$_POST` to fetch your submitted input fields instead of `$_REQUEST`. This is called "POST" because you're sending an HTTP POST request to the specified URL - you selected "POST" with your `method="post"` attribute.

Try this instead:

```
<?php

$mail_to_send_to = "joseph@digitage.net";
$from_email = "joseph@digitage.net";

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $budget = $_POST['budget'];
    $headers = "From: $from_email" . "\r\n" . "Subject: $subject" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
    $a = mail($mail_to_send_to, "Message from a Home page contact form", $message, $headers);
    if ($a) {
        echo "<p>Message was sent, you can send another one</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Message wasn't sent, please check that you have changed emails in the bottom</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

A good way to check if any forms have been submitted is to use `if (!empty($_POST))`, using the [empty() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

If you wanted to, you could write a form with `method="get"`, and then all of your input fields would appear in the URL like this:

```
indexform.php?name=my+name&email=me%40example.com&subject=My+Subject    ... etc.
```

And then of course you would retrieve them using the `$_GET` array. I know this is probably not what you want, I'm just explaining the difference between the two main HTTP requests.

And if you wanted, you could also use a `<button>` element as your form submitter, and it would render the same as your `<input type="submit">`.

```
<button>Send Message</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

POST variables are accessed via `$_POST` superglobal not through `$_REQUEST`, change `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`, this should fix the issue.

Comment: You might want to check that: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php